# Chromedriver is not being found: executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a windows64 bit machine and I downloaded the chromedriver on the exact location it is supposed to be and my file path is this:

`'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\chromedriver'`

Then I wrote this code:

```
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\pushp\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\chromedriver')
```

However, I am getting a file not found error and also this message -

```
'Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Should be double ‘\\’   , example c:\\users\\  also use the extension - chromedriver.exe

Comment: It is now giving this error - 'WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  driver =webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\pushp\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\chromedriver.exe')
```

Just need to add .exe

Comment: But it is giving this error message - 'SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape' and doing the one in the comment is also giving another error :(

Comment: didn't see the \u at the start.

Answer (score 0):

*Set it like the following*

```
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\pushp\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")
```

---

Or

---

```
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\pushp\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe")
```

*You can also install [pip install webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) then run the following code which will install the correct webdriver for you*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: It's still showing the same error - 'WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.' :(

Comment: Double check my code i have updated @AnastasiaTillibiu

Comment: I installed chromedriver in a different location so that chromedriver.exe is not stored in another exe file , so now my location looks like 'C:\Users\pushp\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe' and I wrote -                                                                                      driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\pushp\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')